# Unity: how to make one object stick on top of another?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity. I'm trying to make a mobile game, just room decoration. Is there a way to make the tree automatically jump on the table when I pull it close to the table?

[image]

Somehow the table and the tree both have the same Y value but their pivots are in different positions so I can't add the Y value of the table to the tree. The tree will be much higher than the table. Can we measure the height of objects in the Unity?

Comment: so you add the height of the table - the difference of the 2 pivots

Comment: Ray cast towards the table and use the intersection point to be the height you want the base of your plant. make the plant's pivot be it's base